# $f:\Bbb N\setminus\{1\}\to\Bbb N,\; f(n)=$ the highest prime factor of $n$. Confirm that $f$ is not onto.

Tags: calculus, functions

The following question came today in JEE MAINS(2024). My brother appeared and told me about it.

> If $f:\Bbb N\setminus\{1\}\to\Bbb N,\; f(n)=$ the highest prime factor of $n$, then check whether the function $f$ is one-one or many-one.

I think this function is many-one, because $f(110)=11$ and also $f(121)=11$. Similarly,  $f(8)=2$ and $f(16)=2$.

**What I want to know is whether $f$ is also onto or not. I am mainly confused with this part. I am guessing it is not, but still confirm me once.**

Comment: Hint for your (final) question: what is the [range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_of_a_function) of $f$?

Comment: Consider for example $1$, which is $\in \mathbb{N}$, but never equal to $f(n)$ for any $n$.

Comment: If $f(n) = 48$ what is $n$?  Or for that matter what is $m$ if $f(m)=1$.  The function only returns prime numbers yet its codomain is the set of natural numbers.  So not all the elements of the codomain are hit.  So it is not onto. .... but if we rewrote the function restricting it to $f:\mathbb N\setminus\{1\}\to \{\text{prime natural numbers}\}$ then it would be onto.  For any prime $p$ then $f(p)=p$ so all elements in the domain would by hit.

Comment: This implies that the above function is many-one and into. Please confirm whether I am correct or not.

Comment: @user2661923, actually the question was to check whether the above function is either one-one or onto or both or neither one-one nor onto.

Comment: @AnneBauval, this is the actual question. So, I again edited your edit. If you grant me the permission then I can send you the question paper when my brother will get it. You can check the same

Comment: Thank you for having accepted most of my edit. Rather than a personal communication, better include in your post an image of the paper. I find it strange to give two names ($f$ and $p$) to the same function. In your first version, you did not mention $p$.

Comment: Yes Sorry @AnneBauval. Just now I asked my brother once more about the question. It will be $f(n)$ not $p(n)$

Comment: **To the Original Poster**: You're right, I misread the posted question.  I have deleted my previous comment.

Comment: But once more confirm whether this function is 'many-one, into' or not @AnneBauval

Comment: For any prime number $p$  and the natural number $k$ we have $f(p^k)=p$

Comment: You already proved (twice) that it is not injective, i.e. it is what you called "many-one". And I gave you a hint to prove that it is not onto, i.e. it is what *you* seem to call "into".

Comment: Thank you very much @AnneBauval.

Answer (score 3):

As you proved yourself, that function is *many-one*, *into*, but not *onto*. It is *into* and not *onto* because it does not take the value $4$, for example.

Comment: There is an even smaller positive integer that is outside the range of $f$.

Comment: In fact, the definition of $f$ literally implies that its range is exactly the set of prime numbers. So, no composite number is in its range (nor is $1$).

Comment: I don't think "into" means "many-one" or "not one-to-one".  I think "into" means "not onto".